# Transit gateway vpc attachment

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to do "aws_ec2_transit_gateway_vpc_attachment", and I have multiple subnets in set up. However, I want to pick up a specific subnet id (corresponding to their name) and same subnet will be attach to "TWO" transit gateway id. Would help if you give any clue.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducable TF code example demonstrating the issue?

Comment: resource "aws_ec2_transit_gateway_vpc_attachment" "tg_vpc" {
  for_each = aws_subnet.subnet["eu-west-2b"].id
  subnet_id          = each.value.id
  transit_gateway_id = local.tgw_id.id[0]
  vpc_id             = aws_vpc.my_vpc.id
}

I'm trying to get subnet id of 3 subets from 6 subnets currently I have created. And all the VPC ID (4 in my case). And two transit gateway I have created, so first transit gateway will be assigned to three subnets, again second transit gateway id will be assign to same three subnets. I'm not sure if this clarify, pls tell me for anything to clear my query.